# Question on Stdin

Tags: linux, sockets

I have the following requirement ;

1) select blocks on the file descriptor associated to stdin

2) Now how do I write a code such that select gets unblocked .  The code should make the stdin file descriptor read ready .In other words the code should make the select unblock without waiting  for user to give input

Comment: Who would run this code that unblocks select ?

Comment: Consider that the code is sequential in one program.

Comment: Program should be something like

Comment: Wow, send the above to http://www.ioccc.org/

Answer (score 1):

If we are talking about the `select` UNIX system call, and your are using it to wait for data on `stdin`, you could use the timeout parameter to indicate select you want to block for at most timeout seconds.

From the [`select` man on Linux](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select):

```
#include <sys/select.h>
int select(int nfds, fd_set *readfds, fd_set *writefds,
           fd_set *exceptfds, struct timeval *timeout);
```

> timeout is an upper bound on the amount of time elapsed before select()
>   returns.  It may be zero, causing select() to return immediately. (This
>   is useful for polling.) If timeout is NULL (no timeout),  select()  can
>   block indefinitely.
>
> The time structures involved are defined in  and look like

```
struct timeval {
  long    tv_sec;         /* seconds */
  long    tv_usec;        /* microseconds */
};
```